# Problems using db2 type 4 drivers with glassfish

Tags: jdbc, db2, connection-pooling, glassfish-3

I am trying to create a connection pool for a db2 database in glassfish and I'm somewhat new to the entire process. I created the pool yesterday with no problems, I pinged the server successfully and all was well. The next time I start glassfish, my connection pool is gone! After recreating the connection pool with the same settings, the ping is failing with the following error in the server.log:

```
RAR5099 : Wrong class name or classpath for Datasource Object java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource
```

I've tried moving the db2 driver .jar files around to lib/ or lib/ext/ and I've played around with the classpath prefixes and suffixes, but I've had no luck. It seems like glassfish isn't finding the drivers but I can't understand why.

BTW: I'm using OS X 10.6 and I configured the connection pool in a pretty basic way. I also added driverType = 4 to the properties.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the files **db2jcc.jar** and **db2jcc_license_cu.jar** in your classpath. The mentioned lib/ext/ should probably do the trick. The correct classname is probably **com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource** for use with GlassFish.